# Pre-install docker container into Linux image

Tags: images, docker, iso-image, raspbian

I have the following situation:

I would like to distribute my own Raspbian image with some pre-installed and configured docker containers and, of course, docker as well.

Actually I have tried to set up everything using a chroot environment. This has worked as long as I didn't used any internet connections or I didn't tried to run any docker commands since docker daemon is not running under the chroot environment.

Now I had another idea: I could boot the environment using qemu and then install docker and other tools. But I think this is not a "clean" way. Since after a boot, there will some log files generated, etc.

My goal is to have a "clean" image, but with installed docker and some containers. 
How could I achieve this goal?

Thanks
Regards
Claudio

Comment: I think this would cover your needs? ["Create a custom Raspbian OS image for production"](https://medium.com/platformer-blog/creating-a-custom-raspbian-os-image-for-production-3fcb43ff3630)

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Unfortunately, he is using an already existing SD-Card from an existing RaspberryPi. I also want to be able to automate the above described process. The second problem is, that he has the same problem as above described with the already existend log files etc.

Comment: Have you tried using [pi-gen](https://github.com/RPi-Distro/pi-gen)? This is the tool used to produce the "_official_" Rasbpian images. I'm not sure how functional docker will be while building though... perhaps you could install a "first boot" script that will pull and setup the containers for you?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes, I am actually trying Pi-Gen. But Pi-Gen uses a chroot environment. In such an Environment you don't have access to the internet, and, much more important, you cannot use docker commands since chroot doesn't spin up any docker daemons... It is only usefull for file actions... like installing new file etc.